# Invalid parameter criterion for estimator Pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gridsearchcv

I am trying to create a pipeline for gridsearch in random forest classifer through different parameters but keep on running into error not sure why, can someone take a look?

```py
#Random Forest
pipe_rf = make_pipeline(StandardScaler(),
                     RandomForestClassifier(bootstrap=True, random_state=1))

param_grid = {'criterion': ('gini','entropy'),
               'max_depth': [5, 10, 20, 30, 50, 100,1000,2000], 
               'min_samples_leaf': [1,2,4,8,20,40,80,100,200]}


gs = GridSearchCV(estimator=pipe_rf, 
                  param_grid=param_grid, 
                  scoring='accuracy', 
                  refit=True,
                  cv=10,
                  n_jobs=-1)
gs = gs.fit(X_train, y_train)
print(gs.best_score_)
print(gs.best_params_)
```

This is the result I got

```py
ValueError: Invalid parameter criterion for estimator Pipeline(memory=None,
         steps=[('standardscaler',
                 StandardScaler(copy=True, with_mean=True, with_std=True)),
                ('randomforestclassifier',
                 RandomForestClassifier(bootstrap=True, class_weight=None,
                                        criterion='gini', max_depth=None,
                                        max_features='auto',
                                        max_leaf_nodes=None,
                                        min_impurity_decrease=0.0,
                                        min_impurity_split=None,
                                        min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
                                        min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
                                        n_estimators='warn', n_jobs=None,
                                        oob_score=False, random_state=1,
                                        verbose=0, warm_start=False))],
         verbose=False). Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make your gridsearch work by changing the param_grid to:

```py
    param_grid = {'randomforestclassifier__criterion': ('gini','entropy'),
                  'randomforestclassifier__max_depth': [5, 10, 20, 30, 50, 100,1000,2000], 
                  'randomforestclassifier__min_samples_leaf': [1,2,4,8,20,40,80,100,200]}
```

The reason is that when you use a pipeline the estimator parameters need to be prefixed with the estimator name and two underscores. When you use the Pipeline constructor you can explicitly name the estimator e.g.

```py
    pipe = Pipeline(steps=[('scaler',StandardScaler()), ('estimator', RandomForestClassifier(bootstrap=True, random_state=1))]
```

but when you use `make_pipeline` the estimator name is automatically set to the lowercase of their type, so in this case your estimator name is "randomforestclassifier".

Also you don't need `gs = gs.fit(X_train, y_train)` just `gs.fit(X_train, y_train)` will work.